# Arraylist remove method except out of bound

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a question about my code. I kept getting IndexOutOfBoundsException when i try to get the arraylist.size() after I remove an index from it. When the original size was 8 and then after i remove an index, it should drop to 7. but then it kept being 8.

thanks for your help.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[]args){
    final Integer [] pickMove = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    ArrayList<Integer> possibleMove=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    boolean response = false;
    int counter=0;

    possibleMove.addAll(Arrays.asList(pickMove));
    for(int i=0; i<pickMove.length && !response ; i++){
        System.out.println("arrayList size:" +possibleMove.size());

        int move=possibleMove.get(random.nextInt(possibleMove.size()));
        System.out.println("move picked: "+move);
        if(move==5){
            response=true;
            ++counter;
        }
        else{
            possibleMove.remove(move);
            ++counter;
        }

        for ( int j = 0; i < possibleMove.size(); j++ )
             System.out.printf( " %s", possibleMove.get( j ) );
    }

    System.out.println("# of Tries to get to 5: "+counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be **j** < possibleMove.size() instead of **i**  < possibleMove.size()

```
for (int j = 0; j < possibleMove.size(); j++)
            System.out.printf(" %s", possibleMove.get(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; *i<pickMove.length* && !response ; i++)
```

you should change 'pickMove.length' to 'possibleMove.size()',pickMove.length is always be 8